# How to move a person to a circle instead of copying in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

When I manage my circles (on the page where I can see people in the top panel and circles below) I usually want to move a person from one circle to another instead of copying there. How to achieve this? I've tried to drag-drop holding <kbd>shift</kbd> pressed but this doesn't do the trick.

Comment: It seems it's not possible yet. References [here](http://www.sociolatte.com/2011/07/google-how-to-move-people-from-one.html) and [here](https://plus.google.com/112110080481100162747/posts/FS8eH5tLtbk).

Answer (score 6):

Not possible the way you're doing it, but if you go to the Profile page of the person and click the circle that they're on, you should get a checklist of all your Circles. Uncheck the one you want to remove them from and check the one you want to add to.

A nuisance, sure, but currently the only other way to remove from one circle and simultaneously remove from another.

Answer (score 2):

In the circles tab:

- Drag and drop (no shift) from one circle to another will copy the person to the new circle.  A green `+` icon will appear beforehand to indicate the action to be performed and will allow you to cancel the action.
- Drag and drop (no shift) from one circle to an empty space between or above the circles will remove it from the circle. Here, a red trash bin icon will indicate the action to be performed.